# How to compare the nested models that each come from a different dataset?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have four nested models, each learned from different data sets. Now I want to compare these models together. Normally, people try to compute the F-satistics. But for my case, it's bit harder, because each of these models comes from different data.

Does someone have any idea how can I compare models together in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Look up [funnel plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel_plot). It is a commonly used technique in meta-analysis to check for publication biases in systematic reviews.

Comment: But how it's help, would you please explain more ?

Comment: See the [link] ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x_RIoL2EB8) for an explanation

Comment: I don't think it helps.